# .NET and .NET core on same IIS server

Tags: iis, asp.net

We have an IIS running with a few .NET 4.6.1 apps on it, would it cause any trouble to throw the .NET Core server hosting bundle and a .NET Core app at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you can not remove .net from a modern server, it is obvious that they can coexist.

You do not even have to install .net core if you upload self contained applications that bring their own runtime - all you need to install then is the hosting pack that brings the necessary adapter.

Comment: okay. some other guys in my and the hardware department are worried it's gonna mess with the other apps on the server (never experienced such things myself). thanks!

Comment: Can not. .NET core apps are command line apps - websites bascially start and control a command line app in the background and IIS serves as a proxy. Thus the websites are TOTALLY isolated by definition.

Comment: This answer oversimplifies the facts. Due to the design limitation, there are certain scenarios that things can break. Some side by side problems can be found on either Stack Overflow or GitHub.

Comment: Actually no. Latest if you go self contained as long as you run compatible .net core versions (i.e. from the IIS side, which better is up to standards) you better NAME the so called compatibility problems, because at least I am not aware of anything not caused by incompetent deployment.